# How to hide text after matching and before keyword in regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I would like to match any user comment until KEYWORD. Also I would like to skip variable unimportant text after last comment before keyword.

```
import re`

string = '''
COMMENTS:  
first comment /user_x  
second comment
two lines /user_y
Here is some unimportant text.  
KEYWORD:
Don't match comments or anything else after first keyword like this /user_x  
KEYWORD: <- again
Also ignore same keyword which could appear serveral times.
'''
```

My result doesn't skip the unimportant text.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=COMMENTS:)(.+?/(user_x|user_y))+?(?:.+?)(?=KEYWORD:)', flags=re.DOTALL)
match = re.search(pattern, string).group(0)

print(match)
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
first comment /user_x  
second comment
in two lines /user_y
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot

Comment: In addition, what is the text marker for the start of the unimportant text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
pattern = re.compile(r'COMMENTS:\s*((?:(?:(?!KEYWORD:).)+?/(?:user_x|user_y))+).+?KEYWORD:', flags=re.DOTALL)
match = re.search(pattern, s)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

The output does not contain the irrelevant line any longer:

```
first comment /user_x  
second comment
two lines /user_y
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/R2Qvbg)

**Details**

- `COMMENTS:` - a literal substring
- `\s*` -  0+ whitespaces
- `((?:(?:(?!KEYWORD:).)+?/(?:user_x|user_y))+)` - Capturing group 1 (`match.group(1)` will hold this value if there is a match): one or more repetitions of

  - `(?:(?!KEYWORD:).)+?`  - any char, one or more but as few as possible, that does not start the `KEYWORD:` char sequence
  - `/` - a `/` char
  - `(?:user_x|user_y)` - `user_x` or `user_x`
- `.+?KEYWORD:` - a `KEYWORD:` after any 1 or more chars, as few as possible.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/sAZF7T/1).

Comment: Thank you, it works in this case, but unfortunately not, if the keyword comes later again. Then the output contains first 'KEYWORD'. How can I match all results before KEYWORD comes first time?

Comment: @Plubi Just to make sure: do you plan to find a single match in a string?

Comment: Try `COMMENTS:\s*((?:(?:(?!KEYWORD:).)+?/(?:user_x|user_y))+).+?KEYWORD:`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/sAZF7T/1).

Comment: That's it. Exactly what I wanted. I aprecciate the demonstration makes it understandable.